First-Order Logic with triangle formula algorithm
Is there an algorithm that, given a sentence in first-order logic over a signature with equality and a relational symbol $R$ of arity $3$ (where $R(x, y, z)$ is true if and only if a triangle can be formed with side lengths $x$, $y$, and $z$), can determine if this sentence is true in the natural numbers?

I assume your signature also contains terms for the natural numbers somehow? Why not just say "is there an algorithm that can determine whether there exists a triangle with side lengths $x, y, z : \mathbb{N}$"?

Could you give an example? Do you want to test whether formulas like $\exists x y. R(x, x, y)$ are satisfiable in the natural numbers, if you interpret $R$ as you say?

@NaïmFaviern Sorry, I removed my last comments. Yes, something like the formula you mentioned, but we also allow the use of equality. So, can we write expressions like Goldbach's conjecture? If so, can we determine whether a formula of this form is undecidable to say it's true or not for natural numbers? Given that natural numbers have an infinite set of members, is it possible to decide whether a formula in this signature is true in this model or not?

You can interpret your language in the language of Presburger arithmetic, i.e., ordinary natural number arithmetic without multiplication. The interpretation of $R(x, y, z)$ is a bit long-winded: it has to assert that the maximum of $x, y$ and $z$ is less than or equal to the sum of the other two (so it's a disjunction of formulas of the form $a \ge b \land a \ge c \land a \le b + c$ with $a, b$ and $c$ running through permutations of $x, y$ and $z$). Presburger arithmetic is decidable, and hence so is your theory.
Aside: $0 \in \Bbb{N}$ for me, so I'm allowing degenerate triangles with zero length edges; I'm also allowing degenerate triangles with colinear vertices. If you don't like that, then you can fix it to your liking with additional minor complications in the interpretation of $R(x, y, z)$.
